1980s-ish novel about secret Mobile Infantry-inspired US super-soldiers
I read this in the 1980s before the end of the Cold War and the collapse of the USSR.  In the story the US and the USSR are at war, so it must have been written before 1986 when tensions began to ease.  (Along with Gorbachev's attempts to restructure the Soviet economy.)
The main thing I recall about the story is the blatantly Mobile Infantry (Heinlein) inspired powered armour the protagonists had to allow their plucky team to take on the Soviet armed forces more or less unsupported.  One important distinction I seem to recall is that whereas the MI had, for example, flamers as equipable hand weapons, the powered armour had them built in.  (Which doesn't make sense, but then neither does powered armour with 1980s technology...)
The plot, as best I can recall, is a rescue mission to retrieve someone important from behind enemy lines.  (Hence the importance of not needing support.)
No idea what the cover looked like.  This was one in a couple of boxes of books a cousin lent me, and he got rid of them all a couple of decades ago, so he doesn't remember it.  (There were some truly dire books in there, like NYPD 2025, so it's somewhat likely this is not a classic of the genre.)
Unfortunately what I recall doesn't seem to lend itself to useful search terms...

The first book of John Sievert's C.A.D.S. series, just titled C.A.D.S?

The back cover description of the book, with emphasis added:

They're called C.A.D.S.- Computerized Attack/Defense System. The next generation of America's high-tech soldier. Seven foot tall battle armor suits that are equipped with flame-throwers, armor piercing shells, machine guns and much more, all operated by voice command. However no one dreamed that they would become America's last line of defense. The unthinkable has happened. The Soviet Union's nuclear first strike has left America crippled, tens of millions dead, and it's armed forces decimated. Now the Soviets begin their sweep across the American landscape to achieve complete victory. Only one thing stands in their way. Colonel Dean Sturgis and his C.A.D.S. unit. Now, untested in battle, the C.A.D.S. must race against time to rescue the President from his White House bunker before the Soviet's can capture him and demand the surrender of the United States. The first exciting page-turning novel in the C.A.D.S. action series!

I remember guns with variable-diameter barrels and chambers that could fire a wide variety of calibers of ammunition being a feature of the suite if that rings a bell.
